# How can I programmatically find the mobile phone Operator from a UK Phone Number

Tags: mobile

Recently I am developing a SMS Portal which sends SMS to users mobile phones that are send from the Web.

My Clients provide me the Phone Number where to send the SMS and the message.

From this info I have to recognize which operator this phone number belows to.

Could anyone please give me some light on how can I find the operator of the number of UK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the site who provide the API to collect the Mobile Operator from the Phone number of the whole world at a very low price. Try [InfoBip](http://www.infobip.com/services/hlr/) for your solution.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you are going to find a 100% mechanism. Numbers are now portable.

http://www.ofcom.org.uk/static/archive/oftel/ind_info/numbering/mnp1199.htm

> Number portability is a regulated facility which enables subscribers of publicly available telephone services (including mobile services) to change their service provider whilst keeping their existing telephone number. Its purpose is to foster consumer choice and effective competition by enabling subscribers to switch between providers without the costs and inconvenience of changing telephone number.

However you can get some information here:

http://www.ukphoneinfo.com/locator.php

> The UK Telephone Code Locator takes telephone numbers, std codes, access/short codes, exchange names or the name of a location.
>   Details returned may include: information about where the area is, map location, BT charge information and nearby exchange names.

```
SABC    D/DE    Status  Date    Communications Provider Use             Notes                Change
7790    0-9  Allocated  N/A     Orange                  Mobile services 10 Digit Numbers    08/1999
```

But due to porting a specific number may no longer be linked to the operator it was originally assigned to.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. It is very helpful for me if I could find the current operator of a mobile phone. I have no deal with what was the original operator was. Could you please help me about this?

Comment: As far as I know it's not possible. Privacy laws etc would no doubt forbid it. IANAL however, so this is not a definitive answer. You could ask the user to visit a page and determine the operator by reverse lookup, but it might not be very good in many cases. You may be able to work directly with the operators to get this information however.

Comment: That means there is no API there to find the operator of a phone number of UK? Then how does other SMS sending portals charge their clients?

Comment: Picking a random price page, http://www.intellisms.co.uk/sms-gateway/prices/ you can see that there are no per-operator charges. It's all done on a flat rate, the same cost to send a SMS to each operator. No doubt other SMS sending portals that charge per operator are assuming the number is still attached to the original operator (which you can look up in the URL in my answer) and charging accordingly. If the operator prices are in fact different then they just make money on the average, which typically will still be attached to the original operator.

Comment: Sorry for disturbing you again and again. Could you please provide me the 5 major Operators name in UK with their Phone Prefix?

Comment: You can find the list of UK operators here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_Network_Code#U and then look up their prefixes on the link in the original answer. I don't know who the top 5 currently are however.